# Vertical and Horizontal Slicer Boxes

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I had to go back to Office 2010 from Office 365 in order to create a PowerPivot table for a user who has Office 2010. I had the thing running on 365 but it would not run on 2010. So I uninstalled Office 386 and installed Office 2010. I notice that there are two additional boxes in the Field list areas. 1 for vertical slicer and 1 for horizontal slicer.  Those were not in 365.  Is there a way to get rid of them and just use insert slicer instead?

Comment: I've never tried this but I'm sure this link will help you lot,,, https://www.goodly.co.in/slicer-formatting-tricks/ ☺

Comment: I think I downloaded an older version of the Power Pivot add-in.  Trying a new version, but have other issues.  Thanks